# Ninject: can I persist a binding across many .NET API calls?

Tags: c#, api, rabbitmq, ninject

I have the following ninject binding for rabbitMQ on my website which uses .NET API 2.

When I access many pages on the website this binding only happens the first time.  This is what I expect because of the InSingletonScope().

When I hit the web API the binding happens for ***every*** call.  Is there a way to persist the connection across API calls?

```
        Bind<IConnection>()
            .ToMethod(ctx =>
                      {
                          var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RabbitMQ"].ConnectionString;
                          var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                                        {
                                            Uri = connectionString,
                                            RequestedHeartbeat = 15
                                        };
                          var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                          return connection;
                      })
            .InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: I bet you have an extra kernel per request, thus each new kernel binds per each request.

Comment: I concur with @WiktorZychla. You need to make sure there's only one Ninject Kernel per WebAPI application. That means you've got to adapt the ninject-webapi integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to install the nuget package Ninject.Web.WebApi (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi).  Once I did that ninject correctly re-used my InSingletonScope() binding.